# What IC is in this particular black blob on my pocket calculator?

Tags: pcb, calculator

[image: circuit inside the calculator]

I've taken apart my pocket calculator, and I'd like to know what IC is inside the black blob. Is there an IC commonly used in such applications?

Comment: thank you..I didn't know the name of it before...

Answer (score 1):

This is the main controller part of the circuit. Mainly it is found in LCD Displays.
eg ST7920

please check it out
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's an example of the same packaging technology, yes, but a fairly different circuit.  The one on the calculator is mostly calculator, with a more trivial segment driver.